# Moving large files to different directory

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a 10 GB folder(myfolder) that has lot of files used in an web application. Every week, this gets recreated in a different folder(mynewfolder). I want to move old files to a diff directory and move newly created ones to the right folder without user noticing (or very less down time). I can either do it in C# program or a batch file. Which is a better option? How can I do it in batch file?

C:\myfiles\myfolder --Existing

C:\myfiles\mynewfolder -- newly created

Thanks
MR

Comment: Don't do it in c# if you are asking this.

Comment: [FileCatalyst](http://www.filecatalyst.com/products/faq.html)

Comment: Ensure no file is in use and rename the folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? Just rename `myfolder` as `mynewfolder`. It doesn't take any time at all regardless of how much data or how many files are in there.

```
rename myfolder mynewfolder
```